# Syslog : I am trying to generate separate iptables.log file for IPTABLES,

Tags: 20.04, log, syslog, logging

My Ubuntu 20.4 LTS My efforts are as follows:-

1.) Created IPTABLES rules with LOGGING by mentioning --log-prefix="IPTABLES-BLOCKED: " Logs are successfully generated by iptables, I have checked it in kern.log file

2.) I edited this file /etc/syslog.conf as follows:-

:msg,contains,"IPTABLES-BLOCKED: " -/var/log/ipv6.log
& stop

3.) restarted the syslogd service sudo systemctl restart inetutils-syslogd.service

But I cannot get logs on separate file. I am not using rsyslog and syslog-ng

4.) I have given right permissions to /var/log/iptables.log i.e. 777

Does this syslog service not provide this functionality?
Do I have to use syslog-ng or rsyslog?